# Plot raster using raster attribute in R

Tags: raster, r, plot

I would like to plot a raster in WGS84 projection using R based on its attribute value.

Here is the whole procedure

```
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

shp <- readOGR("final_result.shp")
cell_size <- 0.012
lon_min <- 10.8; lon_max <- 18.2; lat_min <- 42; lat_max <- 48
ncols <- ((lon_max - lon_min)/cell_size)+1; nrows <- ((lat_max -  lat_min)/cell_size)+1
snap1 <- raster(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, xmn=lon_min, xmx=lon_max, ymn=lat_min, ymx=lat_max, res=0.012, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
snap2 <- raster(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, xmn=lon_min, xmx=lon_max, ymn=lat_min, ymx=lat_max, res=0.012, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
snap1v <- shp[shp$snap == 1,]
print(snap1v)
     class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
     features    : 1 
     extent      : 10.9809, 18.18933, 42.07696, 47.89763  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
     coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
     variables   : 8
     names       : snap,CO,NH3,NOx,SOx,PM25,PM10,VOC 
     min values  :  1, 0.0510012180001,0,1.25426065201,1.671099876,0.049, 0.0735,0 

snap2v <- shp[shp$snap == 2,]
r_snap1 <- rasterize(snap1v, snap1, fields=c("CO", "NH3", "NOx", "SOx", "PM25", "PM10", "VOC"))
```

And description of the raster file:

```
r_snap1
   class       : RasterLayer 
   dimensions  : 500, 617, 308500 (nrow, ncol, ncell)
   resolution  : 0.012, 0.012  (x, y)
   extent      : 10.9809, 18.18933, 42.07696, 47.89763   (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
   coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
   data source : in memory
   names       : layer 
   values      : 1, 1  (min, max)
   attributes  :
       ID snap         CO NH3      NOx    SOx  PM25   PM10 VOC
        1    1 0.05100122   0 1.254261 1.6711 0.049 0.0735   0
```

How can I plot the attribute value e.g. CO?
Just using plot(r_snap1) plots value 1 (ID).

Comment: rasterVis levelplot can do this https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/#factor otherwise I'd as.data.frame(, xy = TRUE) and use ggplot2::geom_raster instead, though that's a little abstract at first ...

Answer (score 2):

How silly of me. Just found the answer:

You only need to add y value

```
plot(r_snap1, "CO")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a ggplot2 approach fwiw, untested code.

```
## ... prep as per OP
tab <- as.data.frame(r_snap1, xy = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(tab, aes(x, y, fill = CO)) + geom_raster()
```